# Does rel="canonical" rel="next" and rel="prev" require the domain name in the url

Tags: html

So in the `<head></head>` block of HTML i have the following

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/page3.html" />
<link rel="prev" href="/page2.html" />
<link rel="next" href="/page4.html" />
```

Should it contain the domain name and HTTP/HTTPS value of the site to look like this or search engines should be smart enough to know where they are going.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="//example.com/page3.html" />
<link rel="prev" href="//example.com/page2.html" />
<link rel="next" href="//example.com/page4.html" />
```

Or is this the only valid method ?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/page3.html" />
<link rel="prev" href="http://example.com/page2.html" />
<link rel="next" href="http://example.com/page4.html" />
```

Comment: Link tags do not use or require a closing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those urls are allowed to be relative. This applies to the href attribute in general. The same link tag is used for instance to include style sheets, which can also be included using relative urls.

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)

> **href**
>
> This attribute specifies the URL of the linked resource. *A URL
>   might be absolute or relative.*